# mysql - Too many connections error cause

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am currently getting the two below errors on a LAMP server running Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections in /var/www/html/classes/Db.class.php on line 17

Fatal error: Database connection failed: Too many connections in /var/www/html/classes/Db.class.php on line 23
```

A few things worth mentioning.

- I was running a few cron jobs with wget (changed to curl) which created over 1000 files in root(should I delete them?)
- After I restarted the server the errors are still present
- I checked the mysql max_connections: `max_connections | 151`
- I'm pretty sure that I closed the connection after each query. This never happened before setting up those crons.

I have a snapshot of the server from yesterday and it would be very easy to set that up and get rid of the errors, but I would like to know where they are coming from.

So what should I do to get rid of these errors?

Comment: "pretty sure"?  I would make sure.  :)

Comment: I m sure :D. I checked all the methods that are used by those files which are running by cron and they all close the connection. It never did this before and I've been working on it for a while.

Comment: Do you have free disc space? This error can be caused by your server getting clogged full and not having free space for MySQL to work with. Check the crons don't create big files etc?